# Caching issue in CDN with Varnish

Tags: caching, cdn, varnish

I have a problem about deploying varnish in CDN .
 I have 2 site ,

```
1 in Paris , 
1 in New York .
```

Everysite have 2 server ,

```
1 for varnish cache , 
and 1 for web server .
```

I wanna When client send request to Server in Paris , if web server dont have content to response , varnish in Paris will send request to servers in New York to pull content and cache it in Varnish in Paris .

Can i do that without modify source code of varnish ?
 ...
 if someone have document That can help me solve this problem , pls send to me at email : nohungry381@gmail.com or skype : nohungry381. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within VCL you can setup a failover logic, which is triggered on a 404 and switches the backend to the other web server.

Example

```
backend default {
    .host            = "192.168.50.50";
    .port            = "80";
}

backend backup {
    .host            = "192.168.50.46";
    .port            = "80";
}

sub vcl_fetch {

[...]

    ### Fail over to backup ###
    if(beresp.status == 404 && req.backend != backup) {
            set req.backend = backup;
            return(restart);
        }

[...]
```

source: https://www.varnish-cache.org/forum/topic/195